# What does the term 'Unix Processor' mean?

Tags: cpu

I have Googled around and found a few references to this term, but nothing which defines what it actually means. Does anyone here have experience with such a device? What features must a processor have to be considered a 'Unix Processor'?

#### Edit:

Since some people have taken issues with whether this is a real term, here are some snippets taken from Google scholar which include it:

> The Sparc64 X design concept is to combine Fujitsu's Unix and high-performance computing
> (HPC) processor features to realize an extremely high-throughput Unix processor

> Using one UNIX processor, it takes more than 400 hours to complete the imageodesy
> processing from one pair of cross-event ETM+ images.

> The MmCP will be part of a multimedia workstation's architecture, sharing memory with the main
> UNIX processor.

> Four additional megabytes of memory are dedicated to the
> UNIX processor, but the remaining four megabytes are shared between the UNIX
> processor and the CCD readout processor.

Unfortunately I don't have access to all of these papers, so I can't study them in more detail. But it would be nice if someone who has came across the term before would take the time to answer.

Comment: IMO that would be a processor lucky enough that nobody ported Windows for its architecture.

Comment: You're going to have to give people the context.  Without it you're just asking people to define a random phrase that possibly _denotes nothing at all_.  Setting my usual example aside, I point out that I can get Google to give me many snippets about "Unix cheese", but that does not mean that there is any such notion.

Comment: Could you give a reference to where you found this term in the first place?

Comment: @JdeBP, I actually got this from a CV that I'm looking at - 'tilization of a Unix Processor' is about all the context I have.

Comment: @countermode, besides my last comment, if you Google the term there are a few references to it. Eg there is an academic paper titled 'The Smart Port Card: An Embedded Unix Processor Architecture for Network Management and Active Networking', but it doesn't say much more about the term.

Comment: I looked it up. Its a marketing term. Anthon's comment is pretty close to the truth.

Comment: @countermode, if it is a marketing term, that would be a perfectly acceptable answer provided that you can add a link to where you 'looked it up'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it dates back from the 80s when each Unix workstation/server vendor had its own version of Unix and its own processor architecture. Those processors, e.g. HP PA-RISC, DEC Alpha, IBM POWER, Sun SPARC etc were designed/built for Unix. The chips (and sometimes the hardware platform + OS) were/are referred to<sup>✴</sup> as "unix processors" e.g.:

[<sub>(1):</sub>](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1300&dat=19880822&id=EX5VAAAAIBAJ&sjid=_ZYDAAAAIBAJ&pg=3798,742378)

> The decision of AT&T and Sun Microsystems to collaborate in
> developing a Unix processor prompted other leading US computer
> manufacturers, including IBM, Digital and Hewlett-Packard,to
> establish the Open Software Foundation.

[<sub>(2):</sub>](http://dbclone.com/SystemRequirments.shtml)

> Minimum System Requirements
> .........
> Unix Processor 200Mhz or higher for Unix Servers.

[<sub>(3):</sub>](https://web.archive.org/web/20140404102720/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saponsqlserver/archive/2013/09/20/sap-on-sql-general-update-for-customers-amp-partners-september-2013.aspx)

> Intel processors now benchmark well ahead of any proprietary UNIX
> processor (such as SPARC or Power7+) on the SAP SD 2 Tier benchmark
> for 2 processors servers.

---

<sub>✴: The makers themselves [also use the same term.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-microhist/)</sub>